# In Mahabaratha, Sahadevan is a great astrologist but How he missed out Karnan

Tags: mahabharata, astrology

In Mahabharata, Sahadevan (One of the brother through pandava's) a great astrologist however how he missed out to know that he is having one elder brother (Karna).

Since Sahadevan requested Lord Krishna to protect five of the brothers(pandava's) in Gurusehthram except the elder brother Karna. Hence Sahadevan didn't know that the Karna was an elder brother and a son of Kunthi Devi.

Comment: Is your question if Sahadevan knows about existence of an elder brother or whether astrology is real. Besides these, you are asking definition of astrology. Only one clear question please. Write your question in the body and not in the title.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: My questions are updated.

Comment: Sahadeva, Karna question and astrology being real or true are two distinct questions. Sahadeva knowing future events is a folk story and has no real basis in MB. Why he didn't know might or might not have a relation with his knowledge of astrology. So ask this question differently. Second question if astrology is real is opinion based too. The reason is given in the toolkit "it's clear or not useful." . There are some problems in the question being unclear, too broad. That is the reason for downvote. It's easy to understand. Don't expect reasons for DV everytime. Only some give it.

Comment: I understood clearly, that you are not checked my question properly. Since example only I mentioned `Mahabharata`.

Comment: In case if he (Sahadevan) is well versed **super-nature** in astrology.

Comment: What is super nature? I understood your question and example both. What I'm saying is your example is based on an assumption and a folklore but asserting. Your example covers major part of the question. Some might answer that example and leave your main question. Your main question may hive rise to personal experiences or opinion based answers. There's no need to mention this example which is another distinct question. That's what I'm saying. You understood wrongly.

Comment: @sarvabhouma: As per your concern I have updated my question.

Comment: @ssr1012 - refer to Tantric Yoga texts of ancient Siddhas. Astrology is true - it works through 9 openings of body and the receiver of rays is Chakras. There are 9 vayus in our body and is working with aid of 9 planet rays.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS: My sincere apologies your answer didn't related to my question.